# Why is my directive not showing the correct output?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using this directive in angular: 
https://github.com/codecapers/AngularJS-FlowChart

And description: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709340/Implementing-a-Flowchart-with-SVG-and-AngularJS

But it is not showing the expected output. It should show two **node** as given in demo. I don't know why it is not showing?

Here is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1Sh4647ZECoNaaxOMXom?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="cntrl">
     <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
     <flow-chart
        style="margin: 5px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        chart="chartViewModel"
        >
    </flow-chart>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: It does not seem to be rendering everything correctly. Could it be that you are missing a library? When I hover the visible node, I get the following error: 'hoverElement.scope is not a function'.

Comment: i load all library ..please check my plunker

Comment: I did, that is where I saw the errors. If you inspect your HTML, you can see that it is actually loading both nodes. But the second seems to be hidden by an overflow.

Comment: ok..so how i will display..do you know any flowchart directive ?

Comment: There is quite a good one available here: https://bpmn.io/. But I am sure that you can find some yourself if you look on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is hidden by an overflow. Try setting this on your controller div:

```
style="width: 100%; height:100%;"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fL1OjN2a9Uk8QV6jAjDS?p=preview

Comment: can we reduce the box (blue box) node size

Comment: I think that is done in the template somewhere. If you would try to understand the code, you'll figure it out.

Comment: ok thank for help ..I did it..could you help me getting select event ..on select node it give current object

Comment: Example if I click or select example node 1 .it give "Example node  1" object  and  "Example node  2"  node object if i select second node

Comment: do you have any idea ? click or select event

Comment: The tutorial that you linked has all the information you need. I don't really have the time to go through the entire thing myself. There are different events defined already. One is linked to:

$scope.mouseDown = function (evt) {
    // ...
};